# changing sqoop metadata and going to place it in mysql db

Tags: sqoop

am planning to change sqoop metastore to mysql db(am using hadoop 2.65, mysql 5.7, sqoop 1.4.6)

by defalut where the sqoop metastore  will be stored, like sqoop job definition's (like hive metadata will be stored in derby db)..

created sqoop job's and able to see those by sqoop job --list n executing those as well, how do i confirm that all the metadata is going to store in mysql..

i went through the google didn't get good one,can any one please provide good documentation or google link

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check your *sqoop-site.xml* for *sqoop.metastore.server.location* parameter. It will tell you how Sqoop is configured to use metastore.

You can configure *sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url* to point to your metastore and then create and execute saved jobs.

Generally, we have two options w.r.t metastore:

- Internal metastore - maintained by sqoop and built over hsqldb
- External metastore - like Hive metastore

It would be great if you can post your observations(along with code) here for others to refer.